# INSERT statement does not work

Tags: php, mysql

```
$p_item_details=$i->ProductItemDetail;
$in_product_details="insert into product_item_details(location_id,speial_description,special,introduction,inclusion,exclusion,additional_info,ticketing_details,commence,department_point,department_date,suppliedby,return_details,department_time,condition,hotel_list,hotel_pickup_instruction,itinerary) values('$id_tables','$p_item_details->SpecialDescription','$p_item_details->Special','$p_item_details->Introduction',' $p_item_details->Inclusions','$p_item_details->Exclusions','$p_item_details->AdditionalInfo','$p_item_details->TicketingDetails','$p_item_details->Commences','$p_item_details->DeparturePoint','$p_item_details->DepartureDate','$p_item_details->SuppliedBy','$p_item_details->ReturnDetails','$p_item_details->DepartureTime','$p_item_details->Conditions','$p_item_details->HotelList','$p_item_details->HotelPickupInstructions','$p_item_details->Itinerary')";
mysql_query($in_product_details,$con);
```

Statement insert not work although the connection with the server correct and select db correct I didn't find in my db the insertion

Comment: there is no error when go to to my database there isno any insertion

Comment: speial_description Typo?

Comment: my connection with the server and select db correct

Comment: You need to output the error. Please look up mysql_error(): http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: huh? write echo mysql_error($con):
There should be at least some output. also speial_description is that meant to be special_description?

Comment: i add or die mysql error   display :  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition,hotel_list,hotel_pickup_instruction,itinerary) values('1','','0','
T' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"condition" is a MySQL reserved word. If you have to use it as a column name wrap it in backticks (`)

**EDIT**

And escape any strings that you're planning on storing in the database. That allows the db to handle quotes (') in the actual string itself.

As suggested by Joop, using prepared statements avoids this problem.

The mysql extension is almost dead in the water these days (aside from millions of antiquated tutorials on the web). Consider moving to mysqli or PDO

Comment: oh thank for that point but appear another error     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Basilica, and jump the queue by booking ahead. Numbers are limited to a maximu' at line 1

Comment: ifound solution using $tist=preg_replace("/[']/", "`",$tods);  as te data that come from xml file have '

Comment: Bad solution.... bad, bad solution.... don't use preg_replace for this... if you have to use mysql, it has a mysql_escape_string() function to do this properly http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Answer (score 2):

Better use a "prepared statement", see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642069/php-script-returns-null-when-inserting-a-into-database) link.

That finds a lot of errors and is safe.

Comment: i add or die mysql error display : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition,hotel_list,hotel_pickup_instruction,itinerary) values('1','','0',' T' at line 1

Comment: I saw `' $p_item_details->Inclusions'` with a space before the value. If inclusions numeric then that is problematic. But I saw you solved it all.